# RxJava2 combine multiple observables to make them return single result

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2

How to combine multiple results emmited by observables into one result and emit it once?

I have a Retrofit service:

```
public interface MyService {

    @GET("url")
    Observable<UserPostsResult> getUserPosts(@Query("userId") int id);

    @GET("url")
    Observable<UserPostsResult> getUserPosts(@Query("userId") int id, @Query("page") int pageId);
}
```

And I have a model:

```
public class UserPostsResult {

   @SerializedName("posts")
   List<UserPost> mPosts;

   @SerializedName("nextPage")
   int mPageId;
}
```

Also I have ids `List<Integer> friendsIds;`

My goal is to have a method like this one:

```
public Observable<Feed> /*or Single<Feed>*/ getFeed(List<Integer> ids) {
    ...
}
```

It returns one `Observable` or `Single` that does the following:

- Combines all `getUserPosts(idFromList)` to one observable
- For each `UserPostsResult` must do:

  `if (userPostResult.mPageId > -1) 
      getUserPosts(currentUserId, userPostResult.mPageId);`

  And merge this result to the previous `userPostResult`
- Return one single model as result of all operations.

Result class:

```
public class Feed {
    List<UserPost> mAllPostsForEachUser;
}
```

**EDIT (More details):**

My client specifications was that I must take from social network user posts with no logging in, no token requesting. So I must parse HTML pages. That's why I have this complex structure.

**EDIT (Partial solution)**

```
public Single<List<Post>> getFeed(List<User> users) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(users)
            .flatMap(user-> mService.getUserPosts(user.getId())
                    .flatMap(Observable::fromIterable))
            .toList()
            .doOnSuccess(list -> Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) ->
                    Long.compare(o1.getTimestamp(), o2.getTimestamp())
            ));
}
```

This solution doesn't include pages problem. Thats why it is only partial solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of operators which transform things into other things. `fromIterable()` will emit each item in the iterable, and `flatMap()` will convert one type of observable into another type of observable and emit those results.

```
Observable.fromIterable( friendsIds )
  .flatMap( id -> getUserPosts( id ) )
  .flatMap( userPostResult -> userPostResult.mPageId 
            ? getUserPosts(currentUserId, userPostResult.mPageId)
            : Observable.empty() )
  .toList()
  .subscribe( posts -> mAllPostsForEachUser = posts);
```

Comment: And how do I combine all the results into one model later?

Comment: I edited the post to show how to gather the posts into a list and then assign to the member.

Comment: toList() here returns me Single<List<List<Feed>>> instead of Single<List<Feed>>

Comment: I found a partial solution. See my latest edit in the bottom of the question.

Comment: If you (or someone else) would find a solution to the pages problem I will mark it as accepted. But your current answer doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Did you get answer for this i am also stuck with same issue, i have t manually iterate the 2nd loop or use collections.addAll(..)

Answer (score 0):

If you need join two response in one you should use Single.zip

```
Single.zip(firsSingle.execute(inputParams), secondSingle.execute(inputPrams),
            BiFunction<FirstResponse, SecondResponse, ResponseEmitted> { firstResponse, secondResponse ->
              //here you put your code
   return responseEmmitted
              }
            }).subscribe({ response -> },{ })
```